# Spring security error : No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' available

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have read most of the similar issues that already posted but still I couldn't find a solution. I got error No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' available when trying to run my application. I have imported spring security dependencies in my pom.xml file and I have annotated @EnableWebSecurity in my SecurityConfig class but is still not working I can't find issue.

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>app</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>app</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <description>       </description>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.42</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

</project>
```

securitiConfig class

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;



@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity 
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
          .jdbcAuthentication()
            .dataSource(dataSource);
            //.passwordEncoder(bcryptEncoder); 
    }

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/admin").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                  .loginPage("/login")
                .and()
            .httpBasic();
      }
}
```

SecurityWebApplicationInitializer class

```
import org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer;

public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer{

}
```

Comment: the classes `SecurityConfig`and `SecurityWebApplicationInitializer` are in the same package?

Comment: @JimHawkins Yes

Comment: what annotations do you use in other Spring related classes? Please add these informations to your question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28616569/error-creating-bean-with-name-springsecurityfilterchain/28655714

Comment: I hope the previous post helps. Without the stack trace it is hard to figure out what is going on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you didn't import your security configuration to the Spring root context.

In my Application, I have an implementation of `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer`, where the method **`getRootConfigClasses` returns the Spring root config classes** (I have only one):

```java
import javax.servlet.*;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class MyDispatcherServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer
{
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException
    { super.onStartup(servletContext); }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses()
    { return new Class[]{MyRoot.class};}

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses()
    { return null; }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings()
    { return new String[]{"/"}; }

    @Override
    protected String getServletName()
    { return "myDispatcherServlet"; }

    @Override
    protected void customizeRegistration(ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration)
    {
        super.customizeRegistration(registration);
        registration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    }
}
```

`MyRoot` contains my Spring Beans. Look at the annotation `@Import`

```java
@Configuration
@PropertySource("file:${my.config}")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
        "com.my.filter", "com.my.controller"
        , "com.my.registration"
})

@EnableTransactionManagement(mode = AdviceMode.PROXY, proxyTargetClass = false)
@Import({MySecurityConfigurer.class, MyWebConfigurer.class})
public class DmRoot
{
    private final Environment env;

    @Autowired
    public MyRoot(Environment env)
    {
        Assert.notNull(env, "die Umgebungseinstellungen sind NULL");
        this.env = env;
        dbUserModelPackage = env.getProperty("my.userDbModel");
        dbAccountingModelPackage = env.getProperty("my.accountingDbModel");
    }

   // all my Spring beans
}
```

Look at `@Import({MySecurityConfigurer.class, MyWebConfigurer.class})`
`MySecurityConfigurer` is my extension of `org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` , and `MyWebConfigurer` is my extension of `org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`

```java
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableWebSecurity
public class MySecurityConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    private final Environment env;
    private final UserDetailsService myUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public MySecurityConfigurer(Environment env, UserDetailsService myUserDetailsService)
    {
        Assert.notNull(env, "die Umgebungseinstellungen sind NULL");
        this.env = env;
        Assert.notNull(myUserDetailsService, "der myUserDetailsService ist NULL");
        this.myUserDetailsService = myUserDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception
    {
        String urlPattern = env.getProperty("my.springSecurityPattern");
        String realmName = env.getProperty("my.springSecurityRealm");
        String reloadPairingUrl = env.getProperty("my.reloadPairingUrl");

        HttpSecurity securityAdapter = httpSecurity.httpBasic().realmName(realmName)
                .and().userDetailsService(myUserDetailsService)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(reloadPairingUrl).permitAll()
                .antMatchers(urlPattern).authenticated()
                .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and().csrf().disable();
    }

}
```

This code isn't used for a web UI with user session, but for a service that has Basic Authentication via HTTPS

Comment: I have't put it in @ComponentScan(basePackages = {}) that why it couldn't recognize it. When I have done it it worked! :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the security.xml is loaded by the ContextLoaderListener and not the DispatcherServlet. The DelegatingFilterProxy will only look into the root applicationcontext (which is loaded by the ContextLoaderListener) for the bean to delegate to.

For example:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
      /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```