# Spring LDAP security - BeanCreationException

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security-ldap

Dear Java professionals, 
I'm trying to secure Spring-boot MVC application using LDAP mechanism using instructions from this link: [https://spring.io/guides/gs/authenticating-ldap/](http://LDAP%20error)

But, i'm facing the next problem:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/ldap/DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource

I don't have any clue why I'm getting this error. I tried to search over this forum, thought that found similar problem, but with no success:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28616569/error-creating-bean-with-name-springsecurityfilterchain](http://LDAP%20error)

Does anyone could suggest what I'm doing wrong? 
Thanks in advance.

This is how WebSecurityConfig class looks like:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;

import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

 @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      .authorizeRequests()
      //  .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
      .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .permitAll()
        .and()
      .logout()
        .permitAll();
  }


  @Override
  public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
        .ldapAuthentication()
        .userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=people")
        .groupSearchBase("ou=groups")
        .contextSource()
                .url("ldap://localhost:8389/dc=springframework,dc=org")
                .and()
                .passwordCompare()
                .passwordEncoder(new LdapShaPasswordEncoder())
                .passwordAttribute("userPassword");
    }
}
```

And this is MvcConfig class:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;    

@Configuration
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {    
  public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
  }
}
```

Relevant portion of the pom.xml file:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>ba.epbih.zastoji</groupId>
    <artifactId>Zastoji_v1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>MyApp</name>
    <description>lalala</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.unboundid</groupId>
            <artifactId>unboundid-ldapsdk</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem and tried various things to get rid of the error.  I guess you also followed the example given here:

https://spring.io/guides/gs/authenticating-ldap/

Since the spring boot version that I am using is newer than the example, there isn't a straightforward matching.

Eventually after many tries of adding and removing dependencies... I found the missing dependency is (for gradle):

```
implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-ldap'
```

So in Maven, it should be something like:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
</dependency>
```