# Spring Boot error creating bean with name WebSecurityConfiguration

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to write a site in Spring Boot and ran into a problem when adding Spring Security to the project.

Constantly throws this error:

> Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.we b.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration':
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setFilterChains' parameter 0:
> Error creating bean with name 'defaultSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource

POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.klimmenkov.spring.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>CourseWork</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>CourseWork</name>
    <description>TEST</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
 
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
 
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
 
 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
 
    <build>
 
    </build>
 
</project>
```

Config file:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.NoOpPasswordEncoder;
 
import javax.sql.DataSource;
 
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
 
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;
 
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/registration", "/home").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                    .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .permitAll()
                .and()
                    .logout()
                    .permitAll();
    }
 
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication()
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .passwordEncoder(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance())
                .usersByUsernameQuery("select username, password, active from usr where username=?")
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select u.username, ur.roles from usr u inner join user_role ur on u.id = ur.user_id where u.username=?");
    }
}
```

I tried to change the version of the dependencies in the POM file, but nothing helped =(

Comment: It looks like this might be a duplicate, there are lots of similar questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28616569/error-creating-bean-with-name-springsecurityfilterchain, have you tried here?

Comment: This code wouldn't even work with Spring Boot 3. So the dependencies you show here aren't your real dependencies (Spring Boot 3, or rather Spring Security 6, doesn't even include the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you tried the *current* approach to Spring Security which is not to extend the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` anymore ([check out here](https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter)). You would have to:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class MySecurityConfig {

    public DataSource dataSource;

public MySecurityConfig(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
        throws Exception {
    auth.jdbcAuthentication()
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .passwordEncoder(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance())
            .usersByUsernameQuery("select username, password, active  AS enabled from usr where username=?")
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select u.username, ur.roles AS authority from usr u inner join user_role ur on u.id = ur.user_id where u.username=?");
}

    //customize this @Bean with your configuration
    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        return http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeExchange(exchanges -> exchanges
                        .anyExchange().authenticated()
                )
                .httpBasic(withDefaults())
                .build();
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you tell me more how to connect Security with my db and how to give allowed pages to different roles?

Comment: I'm afraid I haven't used that kind of configuration. In the website I mentioned there are a couple of code snippets that will help you, though

Comment: Ok, but anyway thank you a lot!

Comment: I did a bit of research and tests and I coded the DB security @Bean for you to try (see the edits). I corrected the queries a bit. You only need to add the antMatchers.